# Get https://api.[mycluster]/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, Kubernetes cluster created on AWS using kops and Travis-CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, travis-ci, x509certificate, kops

I follow mainly the following [article](https://medium.com/slalom-build/how-to-build-a-secure-by-default-kubernetes-cluster-with-a-basic-ci-cd-pipeline-on-aws-ebfe0da1c7c9),  at the end I have the following issue while trying to deploy new objects to the cluster

> error: unable to recognize "./[different files].yaml": Get
>   https://api.[mycluster]/api?timeout=32s: x509: certificate
>   signed by unknown authority

I think that I have to pass kube cert **effectively** some where in travis configuration file, any suggestion please

Comment: I am afraid there are so much missing information. Who is providing the HTTP/S service and where. Who created the server certificate of the HTTP/S service? Is it on AWS? Using a specific VPC and subnet? Is there an Internet connection from the subnet? Probably better to show the network diagram and where is the HTTP/S server side and from where the HTTP/S client session is being created.

Comment: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" is basically telling it is a certificate issue and the client side cannot verify who signed it. So first clue required is who provided the certificate on the server side. K8S can auto-generate CA internally. Then the CA cert may need to be copied to the client side trust store.

Comment: Please can you add more details in your question? The article you shared is quite extensive and it's quite hard/time consuming to guess in which step you are facing this problem. Please take a look on this article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give special attention to "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: I think that the problem is due to miss injection of secrets to kubeconfig

Comment: I just solved it by adding my environment variables (certificate-authority-data, client-certificate-data, etc) directly in travis-ci ui, great thanks

Comment: @Smaillns if you can, please post is as an answer providing details so the community can make use of it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the problem was related to cluster certificates, in the article cited previously there is a base64 encoding issue which will make fail the secrets injection. so we have to add information to the **kubernetes config file**, we find the following block in **inject_secret.sh**

```
./kubectl config set clusters.udagramk8s.kops.ucci.uk.certificate-authority-data $CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITY_DATA
./kubectl config set users.udagramk8s.kops.ucci.uk.client-certificate-data "$CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_DATA"
./kubectl config set users.udagramk8s.kops.ucci.uk.client-key-data "$CLIENT_KEY_DATA"
./kubectl config set users.udagramk8s.kops.ucci.uk.password "$KUBE_PASSWORD"
./kubectl config set users.udagramk8s.kops.ucci.uk.net-basic-auth.password "$KUBE_PASSWORD"
```

And what we have to do to ensure the presence of these env variables, is to add them simply by the Travis-CI console, under project settings section
[image]

**Note:** we can get the variables values by using the following command `cat ~/.kube/config`